# How to work with hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

My hash example:

```
{"79_6"=>"0", "85_6"=>"1", "86_6"=>"1", "79_8638"=>"0", "80_8638"=>"0", "81_8638"=>"0", "82_8638"=>"1", "83_8638"=>"1", "84_8638"=>"0", "85_8638"=>"1", "86_8638"=>"0", "79_8639"=>"0", "80_8639"=>"0", "81_8639"=>"0", "82_8639"=>"0", "83_8639"=>"0", "84_8639"=>"0", "85_8639"=>"0", "86_8639"=>"0", "80_8640"=>"0", "81_8640"=>"1", "82_8640"=>"1", "83_8640"=>"1", "84_8640"=>"0", "85_8640"=>"0", "86_8640"=>"0"}
```

I need to get parameters for which the key is `1`:

```
["85_6", "86_6", "82_8638", "83_8638", "85_8638", "81_8640", "82_8640", "83_8640"]
```

Next, i need to group:

```
{"6"=>"85, 86", "8638"=> "83, 82, 85", "8640" => "81, 82, 83"}
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Before asking question on SO, try the solution yourself and paste the same with specific question/error you faced.

Comment: @Pramod, next time you can show your attempts even if they are wrong :)

Comment: @Ilya yes i always do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash.select { |_, v| v == '1' }
    .keys
    .map { |e| e.split('_') }
    .group_by(&:pop)
    .map { |k, v| [k, v.join(', ')] }
    .to_h
#⇒ {
#     "6" => "85, 86",
#  "8638" => "82, 83, 85",
#  "8640" => "81, 82, 83"
# }
```

Answer (score 2):

One more solution (with just 1 iteration):

```
h.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = ''}) do |(k, v), m| 
  f, s = k.split('_')
  m[s] << (m[s].empty? ? f : ", #{f}") if v == '1'
end
#=> {"6"=>"85, 86", "8638"=>"82, 83, 85", "8640"=>"81, 82, 83"}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, i know this is a bucket of crap, but posting it here because of the wasted 15 mins -))

```
a = {"79_6"=>"0", "85_6"=>"1", "86_6"=>"1", "79_8638"=>"0", "80_8638"=>"0", "81_8638"=>"0", "82_8638"=>"1", "83_8638"=>"1", "84_8638"=>"0", "85_8638"=>"1", "86_8638"=>"0", "79_8639"=>"0", "80_8639"=>"0", "81_8639"=>"0", "82_8639"=>"0", "83_8639"=>"0", "84_8639"=>"0", "85_8639"=>"0", "86_8639"=>"0", "80_8640"=>"0", "81_8640"=>"1", "82_8640"=>"1", "83_8640"=>"1", "84_8640"=>"0", "85_8640"=>"0", "86_8640"=>"0"}

a.select {|k| a[k] == '1' }
  .keys.map {|e| e.split('_')}
  .map(&:reverse)
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map{|k,v| [k, v.flatten.join(",")] }
  .gsub("#{k},", " ")] }.to_h
```

Comment: `.map(&:reverse).group_by(&:first)` ≡ `.group_by(&:last)`

Comment: dzyakuy Ilya, spasibo mudasobwa -))

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {"79_6"=>"0", "85_6"=>"1", "86_6"=>"1", "79_8638"=>"0", "80_8638"=>"0", "81_8638"=>"0", "82_8638"=>"1", "83_8638"=>"1", "84_8638"=>"0", "85_8638"=>"1", "86_8638"=>"0", "79_8639"=>"0", "80_8639"=>"0", "81_8639"=>"0", "82_8639"=>"0", "83_8639"=>"0", "84_8639"=>"0", "85_8639"=>"0", "86_8639"=>"0", "80_8640"=>"0", "81_8640"=>"1", "82_8640"=>"1", "83_8640"=>"1", "84_8640"=>"0", "85_8640"=>"0", "86_8640"=>"0"}

new_hash = hash.keep_if {|k,v| v == "1"} # keep only value == "1"

     .map{|a|a.first.gsub("_",",").split(",")} # clean data

     .group_by(&:pop) # group data by the last value which become the key

new_hash.map{|k,v| [k, v.join(',')]}.to_h #transform array of values in string and array to hash
```

Hope it's help, don't be to harsh it's my first answer on StackOver ;)

Comment: While this may be the boilerplate rule, it would seem that not explaining the code has become the norm.